# How to hide the resource in activeadmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, cancan

I create an admin page by using activeadmin gem http://activeadmin.info/
I use cancan to authorize the privilege for 2 kind of user, user manage and book manage user.

My question is: How I hide the resource User when a book manage user log in to admin page? 
[image: Active admin]

I tried something like that but it didn't work

```
 menu false  if can? :manage, BookHeader
```

or

```
 menu false  if authorize! :manage, BookHeader
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use proc for build menu dynamicly

Examples

dynamic label

```
menu :label => proc{current_admin_user.admin? ? "Accounts" : "My Account"}
```

**Display/Hide**

```
 menu :if => proc{ can?(:manage, BookHeader ) }
```

For more info about integrating AA and CanCan read this article

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-cancan

Comment: this one is not working for me. only the proc for the if block knowing the current_user, the proc for the label dont know it

Answer (score 0):

i use this:
for me was *users* for adminuser,
*password* for none admin user

```
menu label: proc{I18n.t "#{current_user.is_admin? ? 'users':'password'}"}
```

Following your example

```
menu label: proc{I18n.t "#{current_admin_user.admin? ? 'Accounts' : 'My Account'}"}
```

will help